# Error by read the file size PHP

Tags: wordpress, post, attachment, filesize

I want to get the file size of an attachment of my wordpress post.
But when I run the site, I get this error ...
Can anyone help me?

"Warning: filesize(): stat failed for http://XXX.de/webdev/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/example.zip in C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\XAMPP\htdocs\webdev\wp-content\themes\web dev-theme\modul-page.php on line 27"

```
<?php
 $a =  filesize($img['url']);
 echo$a;
?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First check and see if the files/dirs are read/writeable.

I would do this inside of a file exist just for best practices.  It is hard to determine what is wrong because you have not specified what line 27 is.

```
if ( file_exists($img['url']) ) {
    $the_file_size = filesize($img['url']);
    if ( $the_file_size >= 0 ) {
        echo $the_file_size . ' bytes';
    } else {
        echo "File size could not be determined";
    }
}
```